# How do I read Child Nodes in Xml file using MVC

Tags: c#, xml, asp.net-mvc, linq

## XML FİLE ##

```
<Title month="1" year="2016">
    <film day="1">
    <morning>
    Fight Club
    </morning>
    <night>
    Inceptıon
    </night>
    </film>
    <film day="2">
    <morning>
    xyzasda
    </morning>
    <night>
    czxsadasas
    </night>
    </film>
    </Title>
```

---

MY CLASS

```
public class FilmController : Controller
{

  public ActionResult DisplayXML()
        {
            var data = new List<Films>();
            data = ReturnData();
            return View(data);
        }

 private List<Films> ReturnData(){
                string xmldata = "myxmldata.xml";
                DataSet ds = new DataSet();
                ds.ReadXml(xmldata);
                var filmlist= new List<Films>();
                filmlist= (from rows in ds.Tables[0].AsEnumerable()
                             select new Films
                             {

                                 month= Convert.ToInt32(rows[0].ToString()),
                                 year= rows[1].ToString(),

                                 film= rows[2].ToString(),
                                 morning= rows[3].ToString(),
                                 night= rows[4].ToString(),

                             }).ToList();
                return filmlist;
    }
}
```

Model

```
public int month{ get; set; }
public string year{ get; set; }
public string day { get; set; }
public string morning { get; set; }
public string night{ get; set; }
```

How to read child node? I want to create a table. I will create a table using this data. I want to keep it on a list.
I edited..
Error: Additional information: Cannot find column 3.

where is the error? I want to read the xml file.

Comment: Can you please update your question and format it better? I can't really ready it, as it is a little "mixed up" (invalid XML with some code, "class" without a class, ...)

Comment: @ChrFin I edited

Answer (score 1):

You can retrieve `Films` collection using `Linq-To-XML` easily like this:

```
XDocument xdoc = XDocument.Load(xmldata);
List<Films> result = xdoc.Descendants("film")
              .Select(x =>
                        {
                           var film = x;
                           var title = x.Parent;
                           return new Film
                           {
                               month = (int)title.Attribute("month"),
                               year = (string)title.Attribute("year"),
                               day = (string)film.Attribute("day"),
                               morning = (string)film.Element("morning"),
                               night = (string)film.Element("night")
                           };
                        }
                   ).ToList();
```

This will return two films, and each will have month & year based on `Title` node.

**Code Explanation:**

First we are finding all the `film` nodes, then projecting it using `Select`. In the select clause we can save variable for each film (you can think of `film` inside select method like alias in foreach loop). Also, we are storing the parent `Title` node in title variable. After this all we need to do is read the elements & attributes.

If understanding Method syntax is difficult, then here is the equivalent `query syntax`:

```
List<Films> result2 = (from x in xdoc.Descendants("film")
                       let film = x
                       let title = x.Parent
                       select new Film
                       {
                           month = (int)title.Attribute("month"),
                           year = (string)title.Attribute("year"),
                           day = (string)film.Attribute("day"),
                           morning = (string)film.Element("morning"),
                           night = (string)film.Element("night")
                       }).ToList();
```

[Working Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/T4hjzM)

Comment: month and year worked successfully,but day,morning,night not successfull..

Comment: @SergenS - What is the error? Can you check fiddle, I just posted and see what is the error?

Answer (score 1):

You can parse your XML with the following:

```
var xml = XDocument.Load(xmlFile);
var films = xml.Descendants("film").Select(d => new Films()
    {
        month = Convert.ToInt32(d.Parent.Attribute("month").Value),
        year = d.Parent.Attribute("year").Value,
        day = d.Attribute("day").Value,
        morning = d.Element("morning").Value,
        night = d.Element("night").Value
    });
```

See it in action [HERE](https://dotnetfiddle.net/vUYBRz).

Answer (score 0):

When i read your xml in a dataset i get 2 tables
Table 1 "Title" with one row and 3 columns
Table 2 "film" with two rows and 4 columns

you read on Tables[0] (3 columns) - and you try to read 4th column of 3..

you need to change your loop - since you need to load Data from two tables.